# Node.js + sass - где компилируется папка с client css?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass

Ставлю на компьютер [wiki.js](https://github.com/Requarks/wiki/tree/master/client) . Не ясно где в локальной установленной папке сохраняется стиль страничек.

`Css` (в виде `sass`) правильно отображается в установленной вики, но совершенно отсутствует папка разметка стилей на локальном компьютере.

Где в установленном приложении хранится разметка стилей. Так как в установленной папке только `assets / server` остаются папки из всех в [данном репозитории](https://github.com/Requarks/wiki/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass после сборки в bundle не изменить. Только редактировать pug файлы с вставкой замены  на понравившиеся разметку.